# Inductive proof, that a certain algorithm does not claim for a not 3-colorable graph to be 3-colorable

Tags: graph-theory, induction, graph-coloring

In theoratical informatics, we were given a certain algorithm in pseudocode:

```
G = (V, E) is a undirected graph
while(G has vertices with degree <=2)
    remove those vertices
if(G is empty)
    Graph is 3-colorable
else
    Graph may or may not be 3-colorable
```

The task is to give proof, that a graph that is not 3-colorable is not beeing considered to be one by this algorithm.
I tried to show that every non-3-colorable graph has the [image] as subgraph, and therefore has at some point only vertexes with degree > 2, but later learned that this isn't necessarily the case, so I'm at square one again.

A hint given to us was to proof it inductively, but I'm clueless.

Comment: Assume that the algorithm returns "true". You have to consider a sequence of graphs `Gi`-s. which appear in your algorithm (where one of these graphs is the initial graph, and one is empty). You should prove that "for each `i` graph `Gi` is 3-colorable". The base case should be an empty graph.

Comment: Not quite sure how this helps me. The goal is to show the algorithm returns false if the graph is, in fact, not 3-colorable.